# How to minimize over-withholding of taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, withholding, income-tax-refund

**I want to lower the amount of taxes I pay in a year.** Currently **I claim 1** federal and IL allowances Additional amounts deducted for FED and State (ILLINOIS): $0.00.

> I'm single and don't have any children
>
> I rent
>
> I don't pay local/city tax
>
> I'm in the 25% marginal tax bracket
>
> My state tax is 3.25%

Here is the break down of how much I'm paying, which I think is too high, and would rather have more money to invest into my Roth, save for emergency fund, etc.

> Gross Earnings: $2,230.76
>
> All insurance payments are taken out pre-tax bi-weekly. $133.45
>
> Fed Taxable Gross: $2,101.28
>
> Total taxes: $543.61
>
> Total Deductions: $133.64

Total Deductions include the following:

```
 Before Tax Deductions:              After Tax: 
        401k    $66.92                  LTD $2.46
        Med     $45.77
        Dental  $6.66
        Vision  $5.83
        Life    $4.72
        Grp ADD $1.28
```

Reducing the amount **refunded** to me at the end of the year is my goal, which I want done by **reducing the amount withheld from each check** (ideally ~$0.00 as close as I can get). Is **filing 0** really the solution to this? I'm not sure how to calculate my tax check afterwards.

Right now I'm paying 543.61*26 = $14,133.86 in taxes a year. Does paying this much/year in taxes seem steep?

```
Here's what I figure I'll owe.

$58,000-$6,300(Standard Deduction) = $51,700.

$51,700 - $37,650 (up to 15% marginal tax rate) = $14,050

$14,050 * .25 (Federal Marginal Tax Rate) = $3,512.50

$3,512.50 + $5,183.75 (amount owed from $0-$36,751) = $8,696.25

$58,000 * .0375 (IL Income tax = 3.75) = $2,175

$8,696.25 + $2,175 = $10,871.25 Taxes owed (Federal and State)

$14,133.86 (taxes paid) - $10,871.25 (taxes owed) = $3,262.61 Refund

FED withholding : $302.10 
FED MED/EE: $31.43 
FED OASDI/EE:$134.42 
IL Withholding: $75.66
```

This is simplified and doesn't take into consideration that I will be paying student loan interest, which will increase my tax refund.

Comment: So what's exactly your question?

Comment: How to lower this tax bill to nil. Is filing 0 really the solution to this? Not sure how to calculate my tax amount while claiming 0.

Comment: I think that 14k/year seems steep. Want to lower that without owing.

Comment: Is your question how to reduce your tax, or is it how to increase the tax that is withheld from your check so that you don't need to send extra in at tax time?  Because those are two completely different questions.

Comment: I am beyond confused, you sounds confused, and all of the commenters are confused. To put things simply, tell your payroll department that you want to change your tax withholdings to all zeros; they will understand you.

Comment: I don't see the confusion. which part of this question confuses you? I want to reduce my tax bill as close to **$0.00** as possible without *owing* anything to the government. Does filing **0** get me to this goal, or is there **something else** I can do to achieve it? Is there a way to calculate how much filing **0** reduces my tax bill. I tweaked my question so that, hopefully, others are not confused...

Comment: "my tax bill" could be 1) the amount withheld each paycheck;  2)  the balance owed upon filing;  3) total paid in taxes for the year.  Which?

Comment: OK - I see the issue here. I want to **reduce** my refund at the end of the year. This is my first **year** working, but, assuming I get a refund, I want as close to **$0.00** at the end of the year as possible. By doing 1) lowering the amount withheld from each paycheck i would be accomplishing 3) lowering the total paid in taxes for the year and thus 2) not owe a balance upon filing

Comment: If you are currently claiming 1 exemption on your W-4, and you go to 0 exemptions, you will have more tax withheld from your paychecks, and a higher refund (or lower tax due) at the end of the year.  That sounds like the opposite of what you want to do.  If this is your first year working, what makes you think that you will be getting a large refund at the end of the year?

Comment: @BenMiller See above changes. This is my first year working my *career* and before I didn't much care and my income wasn't as steady. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: You mentioned that your total tax withheld per paycheck is $543.61.  What is the breakdown of this?  (FICA, federal, state, etc.)

Comment: @BenMiller Had in a comment - Added into question

Comment: I edited the title to reflect what it seems you are actually asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way I would estimate your taxes.  Remember that a bi-weekly paycheck means that you get 26 paychecks per year.

```
$58,000 gross
    FICA tax: $4312, or $165.85 per paycheck
- $3411 before tax deductions ($131.18 per paycheck)
$54,589 adjusted gross income
- $6300 standard deduction
- $4050 personal exemption
$44,239 taxable income

25% tax bracket: $5183.75 + 25% of the amount over $37,650
$6831 total federal tax

$7855 federal tax withheld ($302.10 per paycheck)
$1024 federal tax refund



Illinois:
$54,589 adjusted gross income
- $2150 Illinois personal exemption
$52,439 Illinois taxable income

3.75% Illinois flat tax
$1966 total Illinois tax

$1967 Illinois tax withheld ($75.66 per paycheck)
$1 Illinois tax refund  :)
```

If the $1000 federal refund is too much for you, you can decrease your withholding to bring your refund down.  This can be done by increasing your exemptions claimed on your W-4.  See "[How can I adjust tax withholding so that I don't get a large Tax Refund?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/37375/10997)" for more details.

However, keep in mind that your state withholding is perfect right now, and if you increase your exemptions, you will likely owe tax to the state, unless you increase your state withholding at the same time.

Comment: What is the personal exemption?

Comment: @DukeLuke The personal exemption in 2016 is $4050 per person in your household.  Assuming that there isn't anyone else that will claim you as a dependent (parents, for example), you can take $4050 off of your taxable income.

Comment: I filed my taxes for 2015, I was a student, and didn't get a personal exemption, although I did get 6300 for the standard deduction.

Comment: @DukeLuke Did your parents claim you as a dependent this past year? If so, they got the personal exemption for you ($4000 in 2015).

Comment: IL has a relatively simple income tax: 0.0375*AGI or $1659 in the above example.

Comment: @Joe I had no idea that Illinois had such an easy flat tax.  It's much less complicated than Wisconsin.  Thanks for the info.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

So after a great deal of clarification, it appears that your question is how to adjust your withholding such that you'll have neither a refund, or a balance due, when you do your 2016 taxes next year.

First, a little terminology. The more you have withheld, the more money will be taken out of your check to cover your estimated tax liability. Confusingly, the more allowances you select on your W-4, the less money you will have withheld (more allowances means more dependents/deductions/other reasons why you will owe less tax). When you go to file your 2015 tax return next year, you'll figure out exactly how much you owe. If you had too little tax withheld, you'll have to pay the difference. If you had too much tax withheld, you'll get a refund back.

Given your situation, simply following the instructions on the W-4 should work pretty well. If you want to be more precise, you can use the [IRS Withholding Calculator](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/IRS-Withholding-Calculator) to figure the number of allowances and submit a new W-4 to your employer.

It's a little hard to tell whether "paying this much/year in taxes seem steep?" because you've lumped all the taxes together in one big bucket. Does the $543.61 in taxes per paycheck include Social Security (OASDI) and Medicare taxes?

Whatever you do, it's not going to be an exact science. Come tax time, you'll figure out exactly what you owe and either pay the balance or get a refund back. As long as you're relatively close, that's fine. You can always adjust your withholding again next year after you've done your taxes.

Comment: *Total* Taxes refers to *all* taxes withheld. Yes, great deal of clarification, I'm getting used to this website and sometimes it's hard to catch details that seem small to me, because I'm asking the question.

Comment: @DukeLuke Ah. Since "Total Taxes" includes Social Security and Medicare, that messes up the calculations in your question. You should have around $4160 in Social Security and Medicare (combined) payments a year being withheld. It's probably better to focus specifically on one type of tax at a time (federal or state) rather than trying to combine them all, which will cause confusion.

Comment: If i added OASDI/MED together = $4,312.10. I loathe taxes...

Comment: Payroll taxes are much easier to bear if you remember that this money was never yours in the first place. It's really  a tax upon your employer. It passes through your hands (on paper) only because that gives you the opportunity to reclaim some of it via social programs implemented as deductions.

Comment: @keshlam No, that's not true at all.  You lose a portion of your income through taxes, but that doesn't mean you didn't earn it, it means someone else (the government) takes it from you. If the government changes the rates you end up getting less or getting more, depending on whether the rate went down or up.

Comment: @keshlam Actually, I'd say the opposite.  Instead of 7.65%, think of it as a 14.2% tax including both your portion and your employer's.  When your employer hires you, it costs him that larger amount to hire you, and 14.2% of it goes to the government off the top.

Comment: @DukeLuke `I loathe taxes...` You'd perhaps appreciate them more if there was a way for you to spend the next couple years in some country that had no taxes. There are a few, and a couple are nice if you can work through requirements to emigrate to there. But you should consider using each year's refund as investment funds. Spend more time deciding where it should go. It's very rarely what you make that matters; rather it's what you do with what you make.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how much tax you paid last year, including withholding and any additional amount that might have been due with the tax return. Look at the instructions for the W-4 form, which sets how much tax you want your employer to withhold. Adjust the numbers on that form until the total withheld during the year is close to what you expect this year's total to be -- remember, though, that there's no penalty for over-withholding but could be for under-withholding. Submit the W-4 form to your employer.

Remember that we're a few weeks into the year, so even if you adjust withholding now there will have been several paychecks at the prior setting; you can try to build that into your guesstimate of how to reset the withholding, or just not worry about it.

Do the same with your state's withholding adjustments form.

Repeat on a yearly basis, to account for raises, changes in other income, changes in filing status, etc. until it's close enough that you're satisfied with it. Then reconsider if/when your financial situation changes.

Personally I find that exercise more effort than it's worth, and have simply set my withholding at "close enough". I usually get some money back from the feds and owe some to the state, but either is handled happily by my normal bank account balance.

Comment: Was a student last year, so won't reflect changes in my income. Began my career the first working day of January.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the real world :-)  There really aren't all that many ways for ordinary employees to lower taxes.  You could put more in your 401k, buy a house (for the mortgage interest deduction, which lets you deduct some other things instead of taking standard deduction), or move to a different state to get rid of the state tax.

Comment: Earning less money is one more surefire way to reduce one's income tax.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: Yeah, been there, done that.  And of course now that I've typed up an answer, the OP goes and changes the question.  Some days it just ain't worth getting out of bed :-)

Comment: How was the question changed? Your answer still seems relevant.

Comment: @DukeLuke: Now instead of asking about reducing his taxes, he's asking about mimimizing his withholding, which is a different thing entirely.  My experience, at least, is that for someone whose only income is from a single job, the W4 withholding amount is pretty close.  Increasing it just leaves you with a big bill at tax time, and maybe penalties for under-withholding.